# How do I define a type-aware groovy DSL which can propagate a type to inner blocks?

Tags: groovy, dsl

I'm trying to implement a Groovy DSL, which takes a class name in a top-level block parameter, then allows static type checking against methods of that class in inner blocks, without needing to re-declare that class name redundantly.

(I am using Groovy v2.5.6)

For example, given this class:

```
// A message data type to parse
@Canonical
class MessageX {
    int size
    boolean hasName

    // an optional field to read, depending on whether #hasName is true
    String name 
}
```

I'd want to be able to define things in the DSL something like this:

```
parserFor(MessageX) {
    readInt 'size'
    readBool 'hasName'

    // #hasName is a property of MessageX
    when { hasName }  { 
        readString 'name'
    }
}
```

An attempt at implementing this might be:

```
import groovy.transform.Canonical
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
@Canonical
class MessageX {
    boolean hasName
    String name
    int size
}

/** Generic message builder class for parsing messages */
@CompileStatic
class MessageBlock<T> {
    MessageBlock(Map<String, Object> values) {
        this.value = values
    }

    private final Map<String, Object> value

    void readString(String field) {
        // ...
    }
    void readInt(String field) {
        // ..
    }
    void readBool(String field) {
        // ...
    }
    /** Defines a condition */
    void when(@DelegatesTo(type = "T") Closure conditionBlock, @DelegatesTo(value = MessageBlock, type = "MessageBlock<T>") Closure bodyBlock) {
        // ...
    }
}


@CompileStatic
class Parser {
    static final <T> Closure<T> parserFor(Class<T> type, @DelegatesTo(value = MessageBlock, type = "MessageBlock<T>") Closure block) {
        println "parser get type $type.name"
        return {
            Map<String, Object> values = [:]
            MessageBlock<T> blockImpl = new MessageBlock<T>(values);
            block.delegate = blockImpl
            block()
            return type.newInstance(values)
        }
    }

    static void build() {

        // Define a parser using our DSL
        Closure<MessageX> messageXParser = parserFor(MessageX) {
            readBool 'hasName'

            when { hasName }  {
                readString 'name'
            }
        }

        messageXParser()
    }
}

Parser.build()
```

The documentation [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html#_delegating_to_an_arbitrary_type) suggests this should be possible with just the `type = "MessageBlock<T>"` tag on `DelegatesTo`.

However, that gives me null pointer exceptions when compiling.

```
Caught: BUG! exception in phase 'instruction selection' in source unit 'test.groovy' unexpected NullpointerException
BUG! exception in phase 'instruction selection' in source unit 'test.groovy' unexpected NullpointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

In the above example I also have the `value = MessageBlock` tag, which at least avoids an NPE - but I still get an error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
test.groovy: 57: [Static type checking] - The variable [hasName] is undeclared.
 @ line 57, column 20.
               when { hasName }  {
                      ^
```

I have not yet found a way to get the `#when` method's closure block to correctly delegate to `MessageX` class. I've tried these annotations for the second parameter to `#parserFor` and various other permutations, to no avail:

- `DelegatesTo(MessageX)`
- `DelegatesTo(value = MessageX, type = "T")`
- `DelegatesTo(value = MessageX, type = "MessageX<T>")`
- `DelegatesTo(type = "MessageX<T>")`

Can anyone help?